# Adding Query Tag to DBT Test

Tags: tags, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I would like to kindly ask you about adding query tags for Snowflake queries to dbt tests.
Is there any way to add query tags for tests to project or schema yaml file? I have tried but I could not find a way for it.
I can modify some packages like `dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns.combination_of_columns` adding query tag statement. But if I use the schema tests in the yaml like below, where and how can I define the query tags for tests?

```
models:

name: dim_customers
  columns:
   - name: company
     tests:
       - not_null
       - unique
```

Comment: Have you checked this? https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/tags

Comment: It is about job tags what you sent me. They are used for grouping a set of models to run under a tag.

Answer (score 1):

The [default macro in the dbt package for snowflake](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/blob/main/dbt/include/snowflake/macros/materializations/test.sql), in line 3 calls a macro named set_query_tag(), that it's defined [here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/blob/c0b9274d24ec937d13cea796767c5225c65d48cd/dbt/include/snowflake/macros/adapters.sql#L217). What you can do is to create a custom set_query_tag() in your dbt project, following this example (taken from [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/snowflake-configs#query-tags)):

```
{% macro set_query_tag() -%}
  {# select some property of the node #}
  {% set new_query_tag = model.name %} 
  {% if new_query_tag %}
    {% set original_query_tag = get_current_query_tag() %}
    {{ log("Setting query_tag to '" ~ new_query_tag ~ "'. Will reset to '" ~ original_query_tag ~ "' after materialization.") }}
    {% do run_query("alter session set query_tag = '{}'".format(new_query_tag)) %}
    {{ return(original_query_tag)}}
  {% endif %}
  {{ return(none)}}
{% endmacro %}
```

This will override the default macro and tag all your runs with the test name (something like not_null__model_name__column_name). If you only want to do it with tests, you need to add some extra if/else using

```
node.resource_type == 'test'
```

Also, check [this](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/pull/210) it seems that this is possible since a few days ago, so it could now work as expected with older versions...